# Understanding exceptions inside Task.Run()

Tags: c#, task

This code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }).Wait();
    }
}
```

is confusing me. Run it, and the debugger breaks on the `throw` as I'd expect. Hit f5 and the debugger breads on the `Task.Run` with an `AggregateException` as I'd expect.

Hit f5 again, and the debugger breaks again on the `throw`, then on the `Run`, repeat.

Whats going on here? I'd expect two breaks and then the program to exit. Either my debugger has got in a mess/i've not had enough coffee yet, or it would seem `Task.Run` is retrying the delegate...

Comment: Hit F5 and start the program again? Just guessing ...

Comment: `Wait` is synchronous, that is it blocks until the task is completed.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger program isnt restarting. add breakpoints to the `throw` and the code is being repeatedly run

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh yeah, i know. Dont see how this helps...

Comment: use the `Wait(int ms)` overload. it'll stop after that milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the exact same behavior when not using Tasks:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Since there's an unhandled exception, the debugger won't continue (because the process would crash).

Comment: You can stop this behaviour by unchecking "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions" in Tools->Options->Debugging->General in VS

Comment: @Fratyx so this is a Visual Studio/debugger quirk, not what would happen when not debugging?

Comment: @AndrewBullock: indeed it is. To disable the behavior, use the setting Fratyx mentions. (The debugged process will then exit upon exception)

Comment: @TimEeckhaut It'll also throw an ugly .net program crash error message box to the desktop. Not catching exceptions inside the program is pretty bad practice.